# Django - Best practice for running (switching) dev/debug/product mode?

Tags: python, django, docker

In my source (using Docker), there is a database and my django code.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services: 
    app:

    db:
```

When I debug locally, I usually delete the database in Docker-compose to prevent it creating a new database locally. Then I change the settings in django source to connect to the database of the server

**settings.py**

```
  DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': 123.231.***,
        'NAME': db***,
        'USER': ****,
        'PASSWORD': ****
    }
}
```

or When I develop a new feature, I would prefer to create a database locally to test things our rather than connect directly to the server database.

Well, my question is that how to set things up so we can easily switch between dev/ prod/ debug mode.

In my thought, it should be easy like commanding:

```
python manage.py run dev-mode
```

Comment: I personally just have a git repo with two branches; master and dev.

Comment: [There is no "Best Practice"](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164).   Spread the news to your colleagues as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create **settings** folder in the root directory of the project, and create 4 files: **_base.py, dev.py, test.py, prod.py**

move all the settings to _base.py from original settings.py (and delete it). then in each remaining settings files create your environment specific configs.

for exapmle:

**settings/_base.py**:

```
### import statements

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


def get_secret(setting):
    """Get the secret variable or return explicit exception."""
    try:
        return os.environ[setting]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = f'Set the {setting} environment variable'
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

### other settings
```

**settings/dev.py**:

```
from ._base import *

DEBUG = True

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': get_secret('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': get_secret('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': get_secret('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Then create scripts for different environments dev/test/prod respectively. Considering you're using docker compose. Here is example for dev environment **build_dev.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.dev \
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='super_secret_django_key' \
DATABASE_NAME=my_db \
DATABASE_USER=my_db_user \
DATABASE_PASSWORD="my_db_user_password" \
docker-compose up --detach
```

In this way you just need to execute the necessary script and that's all

Comment: how about `wsgi.py` ang `asgi.py`, since the inner code involve to the origin `settings.py`

Comment: Sure, you will need to change `wsgi.py, asgi.py, and manage.py` files accordingly. `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.prod')`. But this is not big concern as DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE from script file is going to overwrite it

Answer (score 1):

I use two different settings file with the required configuration -

1. settings.py ( has the settings of production env )
2. dev_settings.py ( has the settings of local env )

Now I also create a duplicate of **manage.py** file named **local.py** and hook it up to the dev_settings.py by changing the following line of code from manage.py

```py
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'your_project_name.dev_settings')
```

Thus in whenever I run my app locally I use

```py
python local.py makemigrations
```

or

```py
python local.py runserver
```

Comment: Well, not very professional since there will be many non-necessary code (in extra files). But your method is very simple to follow. Tks for contributions

Answer (score 1):

what is wrong with just doing:

```
if DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
else:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
            "NAME": os.getenv("POSTGRES_DB"),
            "USER": os.getenv("POSTGRES_USER", "hello"),
            "PASSWORD": os.getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "password"),
            "HOST": os.getenv("POSTGRES_HOST", "localhost"),
            "PORT": os.getenv("POSTGRES_PORT", "5432"),
        }
    }
```